# PHPExcel text gets repeated

Tags: php, phpexcel

During tests of our statistics script that produces an Excel file, I've experienced the following.

I loop through my rows in the database, some of the rows has an extra note-field attached to them. In this case, the note is the same on them all.

There are 16 rows with notes.
The occurrence pattern:
[array index]:number of occurrences within note field

- 245:16
- 247:16
- 255:15
- 261:15
- 471:2
- 472:2
- 473:2
- 474:2
- 475:2
- 476:2
- 477:2
- 478:2
- 479:1
- 480:1
- 481:1
- 482:1

Is this an error in PHPExcel or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried outputting the values to a PHP page, with the expected result.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($chr.$iRow, $getAnswers[$gA]['Note'].' - '.$gA);
print "Answer: ".$getAnswers[$gA]['Note'];
print "<hr>";
```

Comment: If you're storing a value in a cell in PHPExcel, then that value will get stored; if you're getting 16 values stored, then your code is storing that value 16 times, not PHPExcel duplicating it arbitrarily for you

Comment: How and where are `$getAnswers[$gA]['Note']` and `$gA` being defined?

Comment: @Mark Baker getAnswers is an Array of answers in our statistics. $gA is just an int in my for loop.

Comment: Further investigations has showed that if I only have a single line in the Note-field, all works fine, but if I have text with "Enter" (NewLine?) this error occurs.

Comment: If a cell has a newline in it, and you want the cell to expand to show each line, then set cell wrapping to true and the row height to autofit

Comment: @MarkBaker, the cell is already expanding the height of the row to fit the text.
But too much text is being showed - text is being repeated.
Please look at this pastebin lines 107-108:
http://pastebin.com/jT03iizE

Comment: I can think of absolutely nothing that exists in the PHPExcel code that could cause this problem, and haven't encountered anything like it in the 8 years that I've been developing the library.... unfortunately, despite that fact that I don't believe there is, if there is an issue in the library causing this problem it may take me months to replicate and find a fix. So all that I can suggest is that if you really believe there is a fault in PHPExcel itself, that you switch to using an alternative library

Comment: @MarkBaker, I don't say it's a fault in the library. Could it be the data? Data type? Or something else?

Comment: I'd expect the data type to default to string.... if it was something as simple as that in PHPExcel, it would have been spotted 8 years ago... all you're doing is setting a cell value, that's a pretty fundamental element of any script that writes spreadsheet files

Comment: Hmm, tried a few things changing the \r\n in the db to \n or \r... Tried single and double quoting the line where note is put into a cell...
Same result.
I've been testing (opening the file) with OpenOffice the whole time, then i tried opening it with Excel 2011 For Mac - Now what fails to show correctly in OO opens up nicely in Excel 2011 For Mac.

Weird?